# How can I get the result type of a member function applied to a class member in an unevaluated context

Tags: c++

I'm not even sure this question's title is correct. What I'm trying to do is fairly gnarly to me so I don't even know how to describe it in a concise manner. Sorry about that.

I have a container of values which are wrapped in some kind of "safe" value class. I need a function that takes a pointer to that container, a reference to one of its member and the following happens:

If the pointer passed is valid, the function returns the value inside the wrapped value.

If the pointer passed is `nullptr`, the function returns a default-constructed value.

Anyhoo, here some code.

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapped {
    T t;
public:
    T& operator*() {
        return t;
    }
};

class Container {
public:
    Wrapped<int> i;
    Wrapped<string> s;
};

// Compiler error with R.
// I'd like R to be the return type of invoking operator* on the member that's represented by M.
// I've tried about 50 different versions of declarations to declare the type of R. This one feels like it most closely represents what I'm trying to achieve.
// R should be the T in Wrapped<T>.

template <typename T, typename M, typename R = decltype(declval<M>().operator*())>
R value_or_default(T* object, M member, R default_value = R{})
{
    object ? *((*object).*member) : default_value;
}

Container c;
auto actual_int = value_or_default(&c, &Container::i);    // Returns *(c.i).
auto default_string = value_or_default(nullptr, &Container::s);   // Returns string{}.
```

Comment: Function can not return types but values. Besides C++ is strongly typed so the type of returned value can not change based on function arguments passed. May be std::variant can help you (or may be it does what you want).

Comment: @ÖöTiib I'm not sure what you mean. To me, here's a function whose return type is based on the argument passed: `template<typename T> T foo(T);`.

Comment: The foo in your example is not function but declaration of template of a function and T there is template argument.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I've rephrased the sentence that I believe is what you had an issue with.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I'd... rather not argue about that. I'd rather you tell me what part of my question is unclear to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
template<typename T>
class Wrapped {
    T t{};
public:
    T& operator*() {
        return t;
    }
};

class Container {
public:
    Wrapped<int> i;
    Wrapped<string> s;
};

template <typename T, typename R, typename C>
R value_or_default(T* object, Wrapped<R> C::* member)
{
    return *((*object).*member);
}

template <typename R, typename C>
R value_or_default(nullptr_t, Wrapped<R> C::*, R default_value = R{})
{
    return default_value;
}

int main() {
    Container c;
    auto actual_int = value_or_default(&c, &Container::i);    // Returns *(c.i).
    auto default_string = value_or_default(nullptr, &Container::s);   // Returns string{}.

    std::cout << actual_int << std::endl;
    std::cout << default_string << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can write

```
template <typename T, typename M,
   typename R = typename std::remove_reference<
                   decltype(*(std::declval<M>()))>::type>
R value_or_default (T * o, M T::*m)
 { return o ? *(o->*m) : R{}; }
```

but you have to call the `nullptr` case explicating the type of the object (`T`) because the compiler can't deduce it from `nullptr`.

So

```
Container c;

auto actual_int = value_or_default(&c, &Container::i);    // Returns *(c.i).
auto default_string = value_or_default<Container>(nullptr, &Container::s);
// ....................................^^^^^^^^^

static_assert(std::is_same<int, decltype(actual_int)>::value, "!");
static_assert(std::is_same<std::string, 
                           decltype(default_string)>::value, "!");
```